# App crash with Null Object Reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am using a AutoCompleteTextView in a Fragment...
but when I use a method which refreshes the Suggestions for AutoCompleteTextView, the App crashes with `Null Object Reference`
here's the method -

```
private ArrayList<String> sugs = new ArrayList<String>();

public void refreshSugs() 
{
    ((AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 17367050, this.sugs));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    //Inflating the Layout 
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false); 

    Button buttongo = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    EditText et1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button buttonsave = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);


    bar = (ProgressWheel) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    i = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    background2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    background3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    readSugs();
    refreshSugs();

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Provide a stacktrace!

Comment: Please post your xml and logcat

Comment: Also the code for `readSugs()`  and `refreshSugs()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be your `getView()` is null.

```
 private ArrayList<String> sugs = new ArrayList<String>();
private View rootView;
public void refreshSugs() {
         ((AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 17367050, this.sugs));

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //Inflating the Layout 
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false); 

         ..... your code

        return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Works! :) thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
 private ArrayList<String> sugs = new ArrayList<String>();
private View rootView;
public void refreshSugs(View rootView) {
         ((AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 17367050, this.sugs));

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //Inflating the Layout 
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false); 

         ..... your code...........
      refreshSugs0(rootView);
        return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, It works perfectly! :)